# Moving files to a mapped drive is far slower than direct network share

Tags: networking, share, mappeddrive, slow-connection

There is one Windows 10 Pro (1909) Client in our company network that is experiencing an odd behavior.
Moving files to a mapped drive brings up to 40Mbs and is therefor much slower in comparison to moving them directly to the network share via \... which brings up to 80Mbs.

Our fileserver is a Windows 2016 which publishes its network share via DFS. These shares are then mapped to a drive via a Windows 2016 Domain Controler. Every other Client PC with similar hardware and settings is not experiencing this behavior.

Windows Server 2003 had a similar issue: https://support.microsoft.com/en-za/help/885189/slow-performance-when-you-use-a-mapped-drive-to-copy-files-to-a-remote

But quite seriously I've no clue how this occurs and where to look for a solution. Maybe someone here has experienced a similar behavior and could help me with this?

If you need more information, feel free to ask.

Thank you!

Comment: Are there a ton of Windows updates running on this one machine? If you log into the machine yourself, are you able to transfer files with more than 40Mbs to the mapped drive?

Comment: UNC access is not slower than mapped drives in the current versions of windows. But I had similar affects with machines using software vom symantec, trend micro and gdata. Removed taht, erro was gone.